# Appfabric cache not refreshed - usage of sharedId

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, appfabric-cache

I have a web farm which contains 4 web servers hosting a web application(x), which is controlled by a Network load balancer, for distrubuted session maintenance i have used `App fabric cache` as my session provider.

I use only one cache server with a region created.

My config contains the Region name and shared App ID, which is same across all the web apps(x) hosted across the farm.

However i see if i access the web apps using IPs all the sessions are different

```
http://10.10.10.1/myapp/file.aspx returns different session values
http://10.10.10.2/myapp/file.aspx returns different session values
http://10.10.10.3/myapp/file.aspx returns different session values
http://10.10.10.4/myapp/file.aspx returns different session values
http://servername/myapp/file.aspx returns different session values
```

what is the use of sharedId in this scenario ? my itention is to have a single session maintained though my app is hosted in multiple servers for performance.

The main problem is **my cache doesnt behave normal, sometimes the session values are not updated even for 1-2 minutes after change**

my web.config settings

```
<section name="dataCacheClient" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>

<dataCacheClient>
    <!-- cache host(s) -->
        <hosts>     
          <host name="x" cachePort="22233" />
        </hosts>
    <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None" />
</dataCacheClient>


<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSessionStoreProvider" cacheName="xyz" sharedId="app123"  />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if you keep always the same ASPNET Cookie (using developper tools in your favorite browser). Because a cookie is also bound to a domain, your browser won't send it if domains are different.

On the cache cluster, check the number of sessions : if you have more than one session, you will certainly have a problem in your distributed session management.

Comment: well the upvote is for the attempt! but the root cause was a missed attribute "sharedId" in the web.config

Comment: sorry my web.config might have mislead you! as i have included sharedId